# Get position of the li jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, position

We have a simple ul

```
<ul><li>text</li><li>text</li><li>text</li><li>text</li></div>
```

How do take a position of the `<li>`, from the top and left corner of the `<ul>`?

`li` is `display: inline`, `ul` has `text-align: center`. Text inside `ul` can be divided to several lines.

Comment: Why have you to know the <li> position ? You can check if this help you : [http://jqueryui.com/demos/position/](http://jqueryui.com/demos/position/)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should use [`.position()`](http://api.jquery.com/position/). You can select a specific `li` using [`:nth-child`](http://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/).

You'll also need to set `position: relative` on the `ul`.

For example, to obtain the position of the second `li` relative to the `ul`:

http://jsfiddle.net/thirtydot/TgXvp/

```
var position = $('li:nth-child(2)').position();

alert(position.top);
alert(position.left);
```

Comment: A small disclaimer: position works for relative to the offset parent which is the closest positioned element. If the ul is positioned, then the result is what is requested else a more complex approach is needed.

Answer (score 1):

Using jQuery's position method you can get the coordinates of the ul and lis and then subtract them to get the relative position.

As in:

```
var vertDiff = $('ul li:first').position().top - $('ul').position().top;
```